# Jquery animation stops when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

After searching for a while I found a piece of code that does everything I need. There is however, one thing bothering me. If the user scrolls the page, the animation stops. If the user stops scrolling the animation continues. Because of this sometimes everything pops up at once.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var st = $(this).scrollTop(),
    winH = $(this).height(),
    add = 500;

$('.hideme').each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).position().top;

    if(st + winH >= pos + add){
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1', 'margin-left':'0px'}, 500);
    }
    else{
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0', 'margin-left':'20px'}, 500);
    }
});
});
```

*CSS:*

```
.hideme {
    opacity:0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3 class="hideme"></h3>
<p class="hideme"></p>
<p class="hideme"></p>
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the `.stop()` part, but I'm too much of a rookie for that. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you just remove the `.stop()`? There is no doubt that is what is stopping the animations. What do you need it for?

Comment: I allready fixed it, by replacing `.stop().animate` with `.css` and then giving `.hideme` a transition in _CSS_